# Is it possible for Adult to change long stay student visa to long stay work visa without leaving Belgium?

Tags: study

Is it possible for Adult to change long stay student visa to long stay work visa without leaving Belgium?
Is there any condition for an adult to get long stay student visa to join school to study French as example for 1 or 2 years extensive studies?

the other question, in case i get a job offer in Belgium and i am staying out of Belgium? which visa type is applicable to apply? i am non EU citizen.

In case i have a Schengen visa with multiple entries, is it possible to change it to long stay work visa if i get a job in Belgium without leaving the country?